# Strict Mode Scope Error on SetInterval call

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is an pseudo example of what I am trying to doing

In non strict mode this works, but in strict mode I get a not defined error when the setInterval fires.  This script is called from another jquery script as a plugin which then makes the call to the init section.

From reading here it appears to be a global scope / context problem but I don't know how to proceed

```
(function($, window, document) {
    'use strict'; // remove and things work
    var opts,test;

    test = function(options) {
        opts = $.extend(test.prototype.opts, test.prototype.defaults, options);
    };

    test.prototype.Save = function () {
        console.log('hi');
    };

    test.prototype.defaults = {
        _interval_id: null
    };

    test.prototype.opts = {};

    $.bla.plugins.foobar = function() {
        var base = this,
            bar;

        base.init = function() {
            bar = new test();
            opts = test.prototype.opts;
            bar.Save(); // works
            opts._interval_id = setInterval('bar.Save();', 10000); //  called but bar is not defined
        };
    };
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a string is interpreted by `setInterval`, it's in the global scope, not the scope of the function that called it. Pass the actual function to call, not a string:

```
setInterval(bar.Save, 10000);
```

And if you allow `bar` or `bar.Save` to be modified, and you want the change to be picked up automatically, you should pass a function that re-evaluates it each time:

```
setInterval(function() { bar.Save(); }, 10000);
```

Comment: you nailed it ... that (both ways) worked like a charm, many thanks!